# Patching a pvc using go client

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to update a pvc label using go library's patch option from [this interface](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/b72204b2445de5ac815ae2bb993f6182d271fdb4/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/persistentvolume.go#L40).

Is there any example on how to use this? Also if the label is not there will patch also add the label?

I am looking to update/add my_label in below object:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-25T18:53:02Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
      my_label: my_value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done the following way:

```golang
    persVolC := client.CoreV1().PersistentVolumeClaims("default")

    data := `
    [
      { "op": "add", "path": "/metadata/labels/mylabel", "value": "myvalue" }
    ]
    `
    updatedPvc, err := persVolC.Patch(ctx, "name-of-pvc", types.JSONPatchType, []byte(data), meta_v1.PatchOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Full example at [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-UyHUU7Viv5).

And [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) you can read about JSON patch standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in which we're going to iterate over the **List** of PersistentVolumeClaims in the default namespace, and we're going to set an specific label `my_label: label_test` to all of those **Items**. You can get an specific PVC instead of List all with the func `Get(ctx context.Context, name string, opts metav1.GetOptions)`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    meta_v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func newClient(contextName string) (kubernetes.Interface, error) {
    configOverrides := &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{CurrentContext: contextName}

    loadingRules := clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules()
    config, err := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(loadingRules, configOverrides).ClientConfig()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    client, err := newClient("")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    label := make(map[string]string)
    label["my_label"] = "label_test"
    persVolC := client.CoreV1().PersistentVolumeClaims("default")

    pvcs, err := persVolC.List(ctx, meta_v1.ListOptions{})
    for _, pvc := range pvcs.Items {
        vol := pvc.DeepCopy()
        vol.ObjectMeta.Labels = label
        upd, err := persVolC.Update(ctx, vol, meta_v1.UpdateOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(upd)
    }
}
```

If you want to check if a label exist and update it, you can replace `vol.ObjectMeta.Labels = label` by

```
if _, ok := vol.ObjectMeta.Labels["my_label"]; ok {
    vol.ObjectMeta.Labels["my_label"] = "my_new_label"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. We are already using Update right now. I was looking to use `Patch` so I don't have to update the entire pvc object.